# Iteration over two vectors and deleting specific positions

Tags: c++, iterator

I am build a game and I am trying to work out the collision detection. I got four classes for now. Game, Player, Projectile and Enemy. So if I shoot with the Player or the Enemy shoots I create a new projectile and `emlace_back()` it into a vector. All my Enemys are also stored inside a vector. All of theses Objects are created with new. 
So my collision detections looks like this:

```
void Game::CheckHit() {

    auto enemy = m_Enemys.begin();
    auto projectile = m_Projectiles.begin();


    while(projectile != m_Projectiles.end()){

        if (//Hit Detected with player) {
            delete (*projectile);
            m_Projectiles.erase(projectile);
            m_Player->PlayerHit();
        }

        while (enemy != m_Enemys.end()) {
            if (//Hit Detected with enemy) {

                delete (*enemy);
                delete (*projectile);
                m_Projectiles.erase(projectile);
                m_Enemys.erase(enemy);
                m_Player->BulletHit();
            } else 
                enemy++;    
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem I have is I dont actually know when I should increment the projectile iterator because I only need to do that if neither an Player nor and Enemys got it with that specific projectile. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the projectile hits the player you delete it, so continuing to use it would be UB. You need to start checking the next projectile instead.

Also note that `erase` returns an iterator to the element after the erased one, so when you erase, you should not increase the iterator, just use what's returned from `erase`.

I also recommend that you use a vector of smart pointers instead of raw pointers. You could then just call `erase` and not have to manually `delete` every object.

It could look like this:

```
void Game::CheckHit() {
    for(auto projectile = m_Projectiles.begin(); projectile != m_Projectiles.end();) {
        bool hit = false;

        if(/*Hit player*/) {
            hit = true;
            m_Player->PlayerHit();
        } else {
            for(auto enemy = m_Enemys.begin(); enemy != m_Enemys.end();) {
                if(/* Hit enemy*/) {
                    hit = true;
                    enemy = m_Enemys.erase(enemy);
                    m_Player->BulletHit();
                    break;
                } else {
                    ++enemy;
                }
            }
        }

        if(hit) projectile = m_Projectiles.erase(projectile);
        else ++projectile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution I will check it later the day and accept your answer if it works for my case.

Comment: Thank you it works just fine. Some logic errors on my side but that’s a good solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you do random deletion like that, it certainly doesn't look like `std::vector` is the right container for you. I would suggest `std::list` or `std::forward_list`.
You will find that `std::list::erase()` returns an iterator to the next element, so you can continue your loop with that one.

Comment: That’s sound like a good point and I will switch over to a list. But my main question stands when should I increment my iterator ?

Comment: As described by Ted, same as with the list, only the iterator returned by `erase()` will be valid.

Comment: Is the iterator returned from std::vector::erase not valid ? Because that works just fine.

Comment: That's not what I said. I said that your current iterator becomes invalid when removing an element, but the one returned by `erase()` is valid.

Comment: Okay I get that, but why shouldn't I use a list than?

Comment: All I was trying to express here, is that regardless of the container you use, you cannot increment and continue to use your old iterator in case of removing an element. I still stand by my original answer that the list is the preferred container type for your applicaton. The mechanism for the deletion within the loop is pretty much the same, but what the linked list does in the background for you beats the vector in computational complexity.  Happy coding!

Comment: Okay got it and I just replaced the vector if a list and I had to change nothing. So that’s great and I notice a small performance increase! 
Thank you!